# Postgresql JSONB | nested arrays gives ERROR aggregate function calls cannot be nested

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aggregate-functions, psql, pg

So i'm trying to convolute  multiple queries and form the result as

```
[

    {
        heading: 'Test',
        subheading: 'SubTest',
        pItems: [
            {
                pid: 1,
                product_name: 'Random Product',
                stock: 500
            },
            {
                pid: 1,
                product_name: 'Random Product',
                stock: 500
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        heading: 'Test 2',
        subheading: 'SubTest 2',
        pItems: [
            {
                pid: 1,
                product_name: 'Random Product 2',
                stock: 500
            },
            {
                pid: 1,
                product_name: 'Random Product 2',
                stock: 500
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

Here is what i tried

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=af81919b853b571ca2f25c96abbad596

But i'm getting this error

> ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `json_agg()` calls. This function is an aggregate function. For each nested aggregate you need a separate `GROUP BY` clause. That's what the error message says:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a5f867d855a0cd6e06e33d2422ae87d3)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        test, client_id, project_id,
        json_build_object (
            'myData_updated',
            json_agg(p_items)
        )
    FROM (
        SELECT
            test, client_id, project_id,
            jsonb_build_object(
                'heading', heading_elems -> 'heading',
                'subheading', heading_elems -> 'subheading',
                'pItems', json_agg(elems || jsonb_build_object('product_name', po.name))
            ) AS p_items

        FROM mainTable mt CROSS JOIN LATERAL
            jsonb_array_elements(mt.myData) AS heading_elems CROSS JOIN LATERAL
            jsonb_array_elements(heading_elems -> 'pItems') AS elems

        JOIN products po ON (elems ->> 'pid' )::int = po.pid

        GROUP BY test, client_id, project_id, heading_elems
    ) s
    GROUP BY test, client_id, project_id
) s

INNER JOIN clients client ON client.client_id = s.client_id
INNER JOIN projects project on project.project_id = s.project_id
```

Additionally, I would avoid to mix up the JSON part and joining all other tables in your case. That's why I put the JSON part into subqueries and join the irrelevant tables last.

Comment: Your code isn't considering multiple pItems 

check your output it only has one item in pItems

Comment: Yes, of course. Your examples only has one product. So what should be taken for pid = 2, if product 2 does not exist? Here I added a second product and it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6b9c77fa1b64832f96d265622fafe00c

Comment: oh my bad.. I forgot about the non existent reference. Thank you for your help again !